# UIWebView not displaying mobile webpage but normal webpage

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uiwebview, mobile-website

I got my uiwebview working and displaying the specified url. the only problem is that the webpage that comes up is not the mobile webpage but the normal webpage. The same url in mobile safari opens the mobile version of the webpage but in my app it opens the normal version. Anyone know a reason for this? I am using storyboard if thats any help

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:website];
   [webview loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIWebView` does not send the same browser header as Safari, thus the web-server does not know which page to serve you app.

You could add an custom header to try and fix the problem.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:website];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[webview loadRequest: request];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried what you have suggested but it didn't work. Which is very odd. maybe it has something to do with storyboard?

Comment: It might be you need an other Header to tell the web-server that it needs to serve the mobile version of the site. You could ask the website builder how the server check wether it is a mobile site.

Comment: thanks, it did work after all. it works fine with all other sites just not with the specific one. which is weird since it works fine in mobile safari

Comment: this does not work for me. some sites stubbornly refuse to display mobile versions in uiwebview. any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You could see if there is a URL parameter you could add in for this specific site since they don't seem to check for the UIWebView agent when deciding to show mobile.

E.G. Maybe going to www.theirsite.com?mobile=true would accomplish it.

Comment: That is not any kind of general standard. It would only work if you knew a specific site used that mechanism for displaying a mobile version of their site. Pretty sure most sites use header information.